# Integral equations problem

Tags: integration

Show that there is no solution to:

$$v(x)=1+3 \int_0^1 xy v(y) dy$$
When the solution $v(x)$ must be of the form $1+cx$ for some constant $c$.

I tried solving this I am getting $x=0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $y$ a function of $x$?

Comment: Not that I know of, I am only given what I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $y$ is a dummy variable for the integration and independent of $x$. Pull the $x$ out of the integral, and write $v(y)=1+cy$; then this says

$$1+cx=1+3x\int_0^1 y+cy^2dy$$

Integrating gives $\frac {y^2}2+c\frac{y^3}3$, so after evaluating this becomes $$1+cx = 1+3x\left(\frac 13 c+\frac 12\right)=1+cx+\frac 32x$$ 
So what we've said here is that $v(x)=v(x)+\frac 32x$ as functions (in other words, this equality is true for all values of $x$.) But that's just silly: it says, for instance, that $v(2)=v(2)+3$, so $3=0$.

Comment: But why don't we get 3/2 x=0 rather than just 3/2=0? What happened to the x?

Comment: @kiwifruit You can substitute in $x=1$ to get that. $x$ is a variable, so that equation should be true for **all** values of $x$.

Comment: Oh, so the goal is to find a c such that this equation is true for all values of x, rather than taking a specific x?

Comment: @kiwifruit Right - that $v(x)$ is a function is the thing to remember. We just showed that if $v$ was of your form, then $v(x)=v(x)+\frac 32x$, which is nonsense when we're talking about functions. (In particular, $v(1)=v(1)+\frac 32$ is just silly.)

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$\frac c3=\int_0^1 yv(y)dy$$
then
$$v(x)=1+cx$$
hence we find
$$\frac c3=\int_0^1y(1+cy)dy=\frac12+\frac c3$$
which impossible.

Answer (score 0):

See that

LHS: $1+cx$

RHS: $$1+3\int_{0}^{1}xy(1+cy)dy=1+3x\int_{0}^{1}y+cy^2dy=1+x[\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{c}{3}y^3]^{1}_{0}=1+3x(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{c}{3})$$So if it should be equal we have that $$
c=3(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{c}{3})\Rightarrow 0=\frac{3}{2}
$$
which is clearly impossible

Comment: But why don't we get 3/2 x=0 rather than just 3/2=0? What happened to the x?